# How Do I Convert Strings To Int?

Tags: c#

I am having three textboxes one inputting hours, one numbers and one power rate and a button
but am having a formatException whenever i try to input values in the textboxes.
How can i fore go this please?
Whenever i compile it runs well but i am unable to input the values.
Help please.
Thanks!

```
int num1 = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);

double num2 = double.Parse(TextBox2.Text;);

int num3 = int.Parse(TextBox3.Text;);
soln1 = num1 * num2 * num3;
MessageBox.Show(soln1.ToString());
```

Comment: On which line you get this exception? What is your textbox values? What is your `CurrentCulture`? You have an extra `;` in your code by the way.

Comment: do you really have double.Parse(TextBox2.Text;); instead if double.Parse(TextBox2.Text);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
int num1 = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);

double num2 = double.Parse(TextBox2.Text.Replace(".", ",")); // <---- 

int num3 = int.Parse(TextBox3.Text;);
soln1 = (int)(num1 * num2 * num3); // <----
MessageBox.Show(soln1.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

try to change parse to convert like this

```
int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);  
double num2 = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox2.Text;);
int num3 = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text;);
soln1 = num1 * num2 * num3;
MessageBox.Show(soln1.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to multiply a double and an integer.
Try casting your integer to a double, and declare the variable you are going to store the result in as a double too.

If it really needs to be an integer then convert it after the calculation

Comment: the problem is with converting string to numbers not type of numbers

Comment: on the second to last line, int*double will never work.
there is more than one problem

Comment: no.result of int*double is double. you can try it. there is no issue there except if the type of `soln1` is int.

Comment: ah yeah .. we are talking about the same issue.
int x = <adouble>*<anint> = BOOM

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using parse use TryParse, like that:

```
if (int.TryParse(TextBox1.Text,out num1) &&
double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text,out num2) &&
int.TryParse(TextBox3.Text,out num3))
{
   soln1 = num1 * num2 * num3;
}
```

Comment: @ShaddyWizKay dont forget to mark this as answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
int num1 = integer.parseInt(TextBox1.Text);
double num2 = double.Parse(TextBox2.Text);

int num3 = Integer.ParseInt(TextBox3.Text);
soln1 = num1 * num2 * num3;
MessageBox.Show(soln1.ToString);
```